# Verify Robocopy Operation

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0, robocopy

I want to run a scheduled script after running a Robocopy Script, which moves files between remote servers.

The requirement of this script is that, it will check whether the Robocopy script has successfully completed its operation of copying from Source Directory to Destination Directory.

If yes, then this script will purge files and folders from Source Directory .

My question is how to find out whether the Robocopy script which was run before has successfully done its job ?

Comment: Often, you can set the `+A` attribute on all the files, and Robocopy most likely has a parameter to remove the attribute as each file is copied (or perhaps it's the reverse).  You might want to check into that.

Comment: Maybe compare-object on the files with the lastwritetime and length properties.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the exit codes for robocopy : http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy-exit.html

Answer (score 1):

If you need actual file verification, a command-line utility Robomate can do that.

After copying files,

```
robocopy d:\foo e:\foo /mir
```

Just type below to verify.

```
robomate d:\foo e:\foo
```

Visit https://robomate.tk for details.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about how to do this in powershell/windows way other than calling bash to run this command.

But using the linux side of things such as WSL, one process you can manually use to check is to write a checksum for each file, copy the file over, and write a checksum for the copied file, then compare the checksums.  Can compare them in something like notepad++ with the compare plugin (run the same line sort on both files so the order matches.)

You can get the checksums recursively with `find . type f -exec sha256sum {} \;`

I typically copy paste the output of each to a new document in notepad++, after sort and compare, it says "files match, do you want to close them" I say yes to close, no to save.  If a file checksum is not matching, then it needs to be recopied.